# Python DataFrame: Remove/Replace part of a string for all values in a column

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, replace

In a Dataframe "df" I have a column called "Company". In there I have a list of companies that end with "- CP" the problem is that the spaces are not always in the same place and in some of the entries the dash "-" is missing. I want to remove the "-CP" from all entries.

Input

| Company |
| --- |
| Intest Apple - CP |
| Intest Apple -CP |
| Intest Apple-CP |
| Intest Apple - CP |
| Intest Apple CP |
| Howard P Delta - CP |

Output

| Company |
| --- |
| Intest Apple |
| Intest Apple |
| Intest Apple |
| Intest Apple |
| Intest Apple |
| Howard P Delta |

This is the code that I have, but when I run it nothing changes

```
df['Company'] = df['Company'].str.replace("-CP'","") 
df['Company'] = df['Company'].str.replace("- CP'","") 
df['Company'] = df['Company'].str.replace(" - CP'","")
```

Comment: There's a trailing apostrophe in your replace, could that be it?

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Company']=df['Company'].str.replace("-CP","")
df['Company'] = df['Company'].str.replace("- CP","") 
df['Company'] = df['Company'].str.replace(" - CP","")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `str.replace` with a regular expression to include the case where the dash can be missing (`-?`) and all variations of spaces between the `CP` string.

```py
company = df.Company.str.replace('\s*-?\s*CP\s*$','', regex=True)
```

Output from *company*

```py
Out[5]:
0      Intest Apple
1      Intest Apple
2      Intest Apple
3      Intest Apple
4      Intest Apple
5    Howard P Delta
Name: Company, dtype: object
```